# List comprehension to Modify a List

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to modify values in a list of list via list comprehension. I'm stuck on how to implement this though when creating the inner list (please see `modify_word(j)` line below).

```
#loop through each tweet
for i in all_data: 
    #loop through each word of each tweet
    for j in i: 
        #find the values we're interested in
        if j not in set(all_cities) and meets_criteria(j):
            #here is where I want to make a list of the modified word for each iteration of i (tweet)
            modify_word(j)
```

I failed miserably with this:

```
 new_data = [[modify_word(j) if (meets_criteria(j) and j not in set(all_cities)) for j in i] for i in all_data]
```

Anyone have an idea on how I might be able to do this? Thanks as always.

Comment: this is really bad idea because your code will become less readable

Comment: Yeah this is ugly I agree, but I have a list of lists now with a lot of junk data that needs to be tweaked based off several criteria (not just a simple replace). Is there a better way?

Comment: wrap into function

Comment: Ok let me try that instead - brand new to it all - appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to convert in the first place?

If there is a need then this should work

```
[j for i in all_data for j in i if j not in set(all_cities) and meets_criteria(j)]
```

> The best way to remember this is that the order of for loop inside the
>   list comprehension is based on the order in which they appear in
>   traditional loop approach. Outer most loop comes first, and then the
>   inner loops subsequently.